# how many records we can insert using Jitterbit data loader at a time?

Tags: data-loader

how many records we can insert using Jitterbit data loader at a time ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it conforms to the limits documented by Salesforce.com [data loader guide](https://na10.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf), as mentioned in the data import limits section.

- maximum field size for imported CSV files is 32,000 characters.

Nothing about the number of records though. But generally, Jitterbit dataloader/SF data loader will work for millions of records without a fuss.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to contact Jitterbit in regards to the maximum number of rows supported by the app. Absent of any artificial limits in the app (say, because of memory constraints), the actual maximum number of rows will be the lesser of (a) the amount of free space you have in your org, (b) running out of API calls per day, or (c) the maximum size of a file on the file system or in a source database.